# Using migen or chisel HDL languages on pynq FPGA boards

Tags: fpga, chisel, zynq

I am currently using the pynq-z2 FPGA eval board manufactured by TUL to design applications. It has a Processor+FPGA SoC Zynq7020 on it.
The pynq python package allows us to interact with the PS and PL quite well via jupyter notebooks.

I wanted to know if we could write the verilog codes for the PL in the new languages like migen 1 and chisel on pynq supported boards. Currently I am writing VHDL/verilog files in Vivado and creating IPs and circuit design in PL.

More info about migen: https://m-labs.hk/migen/manual/introduction.html

More info about chisel: https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/introduction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short : Yes of course.

Migen and Chisel generate Verilog backend RTL source for synthesis. And for hard template you can use mechanisms like [Blackbox](https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/explanations/blackboxes.html) in Chisel.

You can also [Litex](https://github.com/enjoy-digital/litex) which is based on Migen and have lots of core to drive DDR controllers, PCIe, HDMI, ...